# Use embedded template in Expresso's email template

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any way to use embedded templates in Expresso's email templates? When I try it seems to create a blank email...

Thanks, Frank

Comment: From memory I think that should work. Do other tags like snippets work? What does the raw email look like when it comes through?

Comment: From a bit more experimenting, it doesn't seem to work. Any email that contains the embed seems not to get sent, and the "order complete" template (which shows after paypal returns you to the site) shows a 404 page. So guess it's not meant to be! But would be great to have a way to use normal EE templates for these emails one day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so. It's not a normal EE template.